# Windows Universal Application - FPS Limited to Monitor Refresh / VSync forced?

Tags: directx, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, directx-12

I've been trying out DX12 and noticed that the "Full Screen" samples from Microsoft's samples act very differently.

Main Project:
https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/

Desktop Full Screen Sample:
https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Fullscreen

UWP Full Screen Sample:
https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/UWP/D3D12Fullscreen

I'm using the steptimer.h from https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Multithreading/src/StepTimer.h

along with

```
void D3D12Fullscreen::OnUpdate()
{
    m_timer.Tick(NULL);

    if (m_frameCounter == 500)
    {
        // Update window text with FPS value.
        wchar_t fps[64];
        swprintf_s(fps, L"%ufps", m_timer.GetFramesPerSecond());
        SetCustomWindowText(fps);
        m_frameCounter = 0;
    }

    m_frameCounter++;
}
```

To add the FPS to the title bar

Now the Desktop version, I get thousands of FPS, either in window or full screen mode.

In UWP I'm limited to my monitor refresh (60). Is there a way to bypass this to provide "unlimited" FPS, or is this a limitation in UWP applications?

Comment: UWP's can't update faster than refresh to avoid tearing. It's currently always on.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn thats what I was observing, do you know of any documentation about that or if there are plans to change it to allow for customization?

Answer (score 0):

It is right now an OS limitation, Microsoft recently apologies for it with the controversy of the Gear Of Wars Ultimate edition launch, and the problem will be addressed later this year.

Source: http://windowsreport.com/microsoft-fix-universal-windows-platform-framerate-limitations/

Comment: They actually addressed this at build 2016 - Fix should be out in May. Your source is pretty badly written, they even say that its capped @ 30 which is completely wrong.